# Getting Started with LiveCode video tutorials?

Tags: livecode

How to view the free "Getting Started with LiveCode" video course? The first time I got access to it by entering my username and email into the form (the form in http://livecode.com/download/ that says "Start Making Apps Today. Free instant access to an incredible learning course."), and now I can't find any link on livecode.com where I can view it. And I can't enter my user name and email into the form, it says that "This email is already associated with a LiveCode account, log in here instead", but I've already logged in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a support questions. Please, contact LiveCode support for an answer to this question.

Comment: Agree with Mark. Stack overflow should be about programming questions. Contact support and they will sort it out.

Comment: @user2102508 When you signed up for the "Create it with LiveCode" course, you should have got a series of e-mails. You can access the course materials using the links in the e-mails.

Comment: As @hliljegren said, please contact LiveCode support if you still can't get access to the course materials.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of livecode.com/download/, have you tried logging in at the main url (livecode.com)?  If the video course is something that you ordered, it's most likely associated with your account, and might accessible from there.  If you continue to have trouble getting in, perhaps try a different browser.

Recently, they've been moving things around on their site (or have the appearance of this anyway) so most things aren't where they used to be.

Comment: I'm logged in at the main url. I didn't order the video course, the video course is free and provided to registered users as stated here: "Free instant access to an incredible learning course". But there is no link to access the video course. I can kepp registering new users with some dummy email to watch it, but why should one do it in the first place?